# Using EXSLT str:tokenize to split a string into separate words

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am tokenizing a string into space separated words

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" exclude-result-prefixes="str">
<xsl:include href="str.tokenize.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/string/upara">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,'&#xA;')">
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,',')">
                    <elem><xsl:value-of select="."/></elem>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

It always stops at str:tokenize()  function in first line. What is the problem? I am using *Altova XML Spy*.

Desired behavior:

```
Input:This is a small string
Output: 4 2 1 5 6
```

Output length of each individual word

Comment: Can you give an example of a string you are trying to tokenize, and the output you expect? Thanks!

Comment: <string>
<upara>This is a small string</upara>
</string>


Input:   This is a small string

Output: 4 2 1 5 6

Length of each word

Comment: It would help if you included your input XML in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT sample you provided first splits the input string by line-feeds, and then for each line it splits it by comman (So, it is designed to process CSV files)

If you are just dealing with a single line, and want to split it by spaces, you can just do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,' ')">
```

And then you can use **string-length** to find the length of each word.

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="/string/upara">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,' ')">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: If you are using Altova XML SPY, then I believe this supports XSLT 2.0. This means you don't need to include any EXSLT extension functions, as XSTL 2.0 as a tokenize function built in

Try this XSLT instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/string/upara">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,' ')">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It is not runing in Altova XML SPY 
Unknow-function-Name and number of arguments do not match any signature in the static context

Comment: Note that I've made an edit to my answer with a possible solution.